# I need to make a dynamic aggregation in Power Query, by summing or concatenating the duplicated values in my tables

Tags: ms-access, powerquery, aggregation

Here's an example of my data:

| Sample | Method A | Method B | Method C | Method D | Method E | BATCH Nu | Lab Data |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| Sample 1 | 1 | 2 |  |  | 8 | TX_0001 | LAB1 |
| Sample 1 |  |  | 5 | 9 |  | TX_0002 | LAB2 |
| Sample 2 | 7 | 8 | 8 | 23 |  | TX_0001 | LAB1 |
| Sample 2 |  |  |  |  | 41 | TX_0001 | LAB2 |
| Sample 3 |  |  | 11 | 55 |  | TX_0394 | LAB2 |
| Sample 4 | 2 | 9 | 5 | 9 |  | TX_0394 | LAB1 |

I need to make a M Language code that unites them, based on duplicated samples. Note that they might be in the same batch and/or in the same lab, but they won't ever be made the same method twice.

So I can't pass the column names, because they keep changing, and I wanted to do it passaing the column names dynamically.

**OBS: I have the possibility to make a linked table of the source to a Microsoft Access and make this with SQL, but I couldn't find a text aggregation function in MS Access library. There it's possible to each column name with no problem. (Just a matter that no one else knows M Language in my company and I can't let this be non-automated)
**

This is the what I have been trying to improve, but I keep have some errors:
1.Both goruped columns have "Errors" in all of the cells
2.Evaluation running out of memory

I can't discover what I'm doing wrong here.

```
let
    Source = ALS,
    schema = Table.Schema(Source),
    columns = schema[Name],
    types = schema[Kind],
    Table = Table.FromColumns({columns,types}),
    Number_Columns = Table.SelectRows(Table, each ([Column2] = "number")),
    Other_Columns = Table.SelectRows(Table, each ([Column2] <> "number")),
    numCols = Table.Column(Number_Columns, "Column1"),
    textColsSID = List.Select(Table.ColumnNames(Source), each Table.Column(Source, _) <> type number),
    textCols = List.RemoveItems(textColsSID, {"Sample ID"}),
    groupedNum = Table.Group(Source, {"Sample ID"},List.Transform(numCols, each {_, (nmr) => List.Sum(nmr),type nullable number})),
    groupedText = Table.Group(Source,{"Sample ID"},List.Transform(textCols, each {_, (tbl) => Text.Combine(tbl, "_")})),
    merged = Table.NestedJoin(groupedNum, {"Sample ID"}, groupedText, {"Sample ID"}, "merged"),
    expanded = Table.ExpandTableColumn(merged, "merged", Table.ColumnNames(merged{1}[merged]))
in
    expanded
```

This is what I expected to have:

| Sample | Method A | Method B | Method C | Method D | Method E | BATCH Nu | Lab Data |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| Sample 1 | 1 | 2 | 5 | 9 | 8 | TX_0001_TX_0002 | LAB1_LAB2 |
| Sample 2 | 7 | 8 | 8 | 23 | 41 | TX_0001_TX_0001 | LAB1_LAB1 |
| Sample 3 |  |  | 11 | 55 |  | TX_0394 | LAB2 |
| Sample 4 | 2 | 9 | 5 | 9 |  | TX_0394 | LAB1 |

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One way.  You could probably do this all within the group as well

```
let Source = Excel.CurrentWorkbook(){[Name="Table1"]}[Content],
names = List.Distinct(List.Select(Table.ColumnNames(Source), each Text.Contains(_,"Method"))),
#"Grouped Rows" = Table.Group(Source, {"Sample"}, {{"data", each _, type table }}),
#"Added Custom" = Table.AddColumn(#"Grouped Rows", "Batch Nu", each Text.Combine(List.Distinct([data][BATCH Nu]),"_")),
#"Added Custom1" = Table.AddColumn(#"Added Custom", "Lab Data", each Text.Combine(List.Distinct([data][Lab Data]),"_")),
#"Added Custom2" = Table.AddColumn(#"Added Custom1", "Custom", each Table.SelectRows(Table.UnpivotOtherColumns([data], {"Sample"}, "Attribute", "Value"), each List.Contains(names,[Attribute]))),
#"Added Custom3" = Table.AddColumn(#"Added Custom2", "Custom.1", each Table.Pivot([Custom], List.Distinct([Custom][Attribute]), "Attribute", "Value", List.Sum)),
#"Expanded Custom.1" = Table.ExpandTableColumn(#"Added Custom3" , "Custom.1", names,names),
#"Removed Columns" = Table.RemoveColumns(#"Expanded Custom.1",{"data", "Custom"})
in #"Removed Columns"
```

[image]

Answer (score 2):

Here is a method which assumes only that the first column is a column which will be used to group the different samples.

It makes no assumptions about any column names, or the numbers of columns.

It tests the first 10 rows in each column (after removing any nulls) to determine if the column type can be `type number`, otherwise it will assume `type text`.

If there are other possible data types, the type detection code can be expanded.

```
let
    Source = Excel.CurrentWorkbook(){[Name="Table1"]}[Content],

//dynamically detect data types from first ten rows
//only detecting "text" and "number"
    colNames = Table.ColumnNames(Source),
    checkRows = 10,
    colTestTypes = List.Generate(
        ()=>[t=
            let 
                Values = List.FirstN(Table.Column(Source,colNames{0}),10),
                tryNumber = List.Transform(List.RemoveNulls(Values), each (try Number.From(_))[HasError])
            in 
                tryNumber,  idx=0],
        each [idx] < List.Count(colNames),
        each [t=
            let 
                Values = List.FirstN(Table.Column(Source,colNames{[idx]+1}),10),
                tryNumber = List.Transform(List.RemoveNulls(Values), each (try Number.From(_))[HasError])
            in 
                tryNumber,  idx=[idx]+1],
        each [t]),
    colTypes = List.Transform(colTestTypes, each if List.AllTrue(_) then type text else type number),

//Group and Sum or Concatenate columns, keying on the first column
    group = Table.Group(Source,{colNames{0}},
        {"rw", (t)=>
        Record.FromList(
            List.Generate(
                ()=>[rw=if colTypes{1} = type number  
                            then List.Sum(Table.Column(t,colNames{1}))
                            else Text.Combine(Table.Column(t,colNames{1}),"_"), 
                        idx=1],
                    each [idx] < List.Count(colNames),
                    each [rw=if colTypes{[idx]+1} = type number  
                                then List.Sum(Table.Column(t,colNames{[idx]+1}))
                                else Text.Combine(Table.Column(t,colNames{[idx]+1}),"_"), 
                            idx=[idx]+1],
                    each [rw]), List.RemoveFirstN(colNames,1)), type record}
        ),

//expand the record column and set the data types
    #"Expanded rw" = Table.ExpandRecordColumn(group, "rw", List.RemoveFirstN(colNames,1)),
    #"Set Data Type" = Table.TransformColumnTypes(#"Expanded rw", List.Zip({colNames, colTypes}))

in
    #"Set Data Type"
```

***Original Data***
[image]

***Results***
[image]